# MVVM model in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, mvvm, swiftui, view, viewmodel

I want to separate view from view model according to MVVM. How would I create a model in SwiftUI? I read that one should use struct rather than class.

As an example I have a model for a park where you can plant trees in:

```swift
// View Model
struct Park {
  var numberOfTrees = 0
  func plantTree() {
    numberOfTrees += 1 // Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable
  }
}

// View
struct ParkView: View {
  var park: Park
  var body: some View {
    // …
  }
}
```

Read things about `@State` in such things, that make structs somewhat mutable, so I tried:

```swift
struct Park {
  @State var numberOfTrees = 0 // Enum 'State' cannot be used as an attribute
  func plantTree() {
    numberOfTrees += 1 // Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable
  }
}
```

I did use `@State` successfully directly in a `View`. This doesn’t help with separating the view model code though.

I could use `class`:

```swift
class Park: ObservableObject {
  var numberOfTrees = 0
  func plantTree() {
    numberOfTrees += 1
  }
}
```

…but then I would have trouble using this view model nested in another one, say `City`:

```swift
struct City {
  @ObservedObject var centerPark: Park
}
```

Changes in `centerPark` wouldn’t be published as `Park` now is reference type (at least not in my tests or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68400530/changes-in-nested-observedobject-do-not-updated-the-ui)). Also, I would like to know how you solve this using a `struct`.

Comment: You only use @State in a View. You don’t have one view model inside as a property of another. Make sure you understand the difference between view model and model

Comment: Thank you. Think that helps. View is `ParkView`, view model is `Park` and the model is the database table structure, right?

Comment: Also: if I can’t adjust properties in my `struct` ViewModel, does that mean I should use `class`?

Comment: `Park` is your model (where the data is stored), `CityVM` is your ViewModel, which makes the model available to the views, and `ParkView` is the view. And yes, you CAN change properties in your model struct, no need for class. you just have to mark the changing funcs `mutating`as in the example.

Comment: What if I wanted to make a view `ParkView` that represents a `ParkModel`? Wouldn’t I need a `ParkViewModel`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as a starting point:

```
// Model
struct Park {
    var numberOfTrees = 0
    mutating func plantTree() {  // `mutating`gets rid of your error
        numberOfTrees += 1
    }
}

// View Model
class CityVM: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var park = Park() // creates a Park and publishes it to the views
    
    // ... other @Published things ...
    
    // Intents:
    func plantTree() {
        park.plantTree()
    }
}


// View
struct ParkView: View {
    
    // create the ViewModel, which creates the model(s)
    // usually you would do this in the App struct and make available to all views by .environmentObject
    @StateObject var city = CityVM()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("My city has \(city.park.numberOfTrees) trees.")
            
            Button("Plant one more") {
                city.plantTree()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like the canonical implementation of a MVVM, where the `ParkView` is a "component" also responsible for creating the view model, and `Park` represents a model. However, the model could be anything from such simple as a struct, as something much more complex.

Answer (score 2):

`mutating func` is the fix but I thought I'd include some other info below:

We don't use MVVM with SwiftUI because we don't use classes for transient view state and we don't control the View in the MVVM/MVC sense. SwiftUI creates and updates the real view objects automatically for us, i.e. UILabels, UITableView etc. The SwiftUI `View` structs are essentially the view model already, so if you were to recreate that as an object not only will you be needlessly make your code more complex but also would introduce object reference bugs SwiftUI is trying to eliminate by using structs. With property wrappers like `@State` and `@Binding` SwiftUI is doing some magic to make the struct behave like an object it is not a good idea to ignore that. To make your View structs more testable you can extract related vars into a struct and use mutating funcs like this:

```
// View Model
struct ParkConfig {
  var numberOfTrees = 0
  mutating func plantTree() {
    numberOfTrees += 1
  }
}

struct ContentView {
    @State var parkConfig = ParkConfig()

    var body: some View {
        ParkView(config: $parkConfig)
    }
}

// View
struct ParkView: View {
  @Binding var config: ParkConfig
  var body: some View {
      Button("Click Me") {
          config.plantTree()
      }
  }
}
```

You can see Apple demonstrate this pattern in [Data Essentials in SwiftUI WWDC 2020](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10040/?time=258) at 4:18 where he says "EditorConfig can maintain invariants on its properties and be tested independently. And because EditorConfig is a value type, any change to a property of EditorConfig, like its progress, is visible as a change to EditorConfig itself."

Comment: as much as I agree with you its not so nice to downvote an answer, which explicitly addresses the MVVM OP question.

Comment: Interesting minimalistic idea. However, I don't see a conceptual advantage using a struct `ParkConfig` instead of an `ObservedObject`. In case of a struct, you cannot access it from outside. Having a more complex model, implemented as ObservedObject, which has a pure, functional nucleon and communicates with the outside world through "side effects", is more feasible IMO. Think of user "intent" which need to processed somehow in the model, and need to be "send" somehow to the model.

Comment: So, you advise to use `structs`? What would you recommend for methods with say timers in them that change properties? `class` in this case?

Comment: @CouchDeveloper take a read at this and note the risk of logic errors with classes: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/choosing_between_structures_and_classes and also the point of defining a source of truth is that it cannot be accessed from outside.

Comment: @JaneTrifels That wouldn't be the problem. `@State` is a var, and whether you use a mutating function to change a member variable (which needs to be var as well), or if you change the member var via a property isn't relevant. The disadvantage here is, that you need to follow the rules for UIView `@State`, where one rule is, that you can only change it when `body` is not currently executed, 2. `@State` shall be strictly private to the view, and 3. it must be on the main thread. For use as a "Model" (in MVVM), that's too limited IMHO, even in very simple use cases.

Comment: From the future: Observable is now a reasonable, Apple prescribed, way to back a SwiftUI view. And the Observable macro is only usable on classes. For anyone interested, see "Discover Observation in SwiftUI" WWDC talk from 2023