# Why is objectWillChange sink not getting called?

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

In an effort to maintain the "single source of truth," I have a data model that contains a User object (class, not struct), and a UserManager object that performs user-related actions at the behest of SwiftUI views. All the members of User are basic types and are published.

The UserManager holds a reference to this User object that resides in the central data model. This User object might be changed by a background process, as the result of polling a remote database (for example). However, changes to embedded objects do not trigger notifications that their parent has changed, and thus wouldn't be reflected by a UI looking at the UserManager.

Therefore I wanted the UserManager to subscribe to changes to its User object, and then alert the UI to refresh itself.

So I set up the following, being sure to store a reference to the cancellable pipeline.

```
class User : Codable, Equatable, ObservableObject
{
    @Published var  ID: String = ""
    @Published var  pw: String = ""
    @Published var  username:  String = ""
    @Published var  firstName: String = ""
    @Published var  lastName: String = ""
...
}

class CentralModel : ObservableObject
{
    @Published var  user: User

    init()
    {
        user = User()
    }
...
}

class UserManager : ObservableObject
{
    var model: CentralModel
    private var pubPipelines: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

    init(withModel: CentralModel)
    {
        self.model = withModel
        model.user.objectWillChange.sink(receiveValue: { newUser in
            print("The new user is \(newUser)") })
            .store(in: &pubPipelines)

        startValidationCheckTimer()
    }

    func startValidationCheckTimer()
    {
        self.validationTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.timedValidationCheck), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func timedValidationCheck()
    {
        Task { @MainActor in
            user.firstName = UUID().uuidString
            print("Set user's first name to \(user.firstName)")
        }
    }
...
}
```

In the app I create a timer that randomly changes `user.firstName`. The `objectWillChange` sink is never called. Because I'm subscribing directly to the embedded User's publisher, I wouldn't expect that the UserManager's pointer to it needs to change to trigger a publication.

So the first question is why the sink's not receiving anything. I even tried setting up a dummy User in CentralModel and subscribing to that one, but swapping it out entirely by setting it to User() (thus changing CentralModel's pointer to it). Still nothing.

Beyond that, I'm not a huge fan of this type of design, but I don't see how else to have a "single source of truth."

Comment: Don't you need to maintain a reference to the sink (ie `AnyCancellable`) for it to work?  So you'd need a property in the class to store it against (ie `private var sinkRef: AnyCancellable?`) and then assign the result from the sink call `sinkRef = model.user.objectWillChange.sink(...)` ... I could be way off, but that's my understanding

Comment: Yes, and I am. It's being stored in pubPipelines. It's the very last line of code. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed that - I do it the other way round (assign it directly)

Comment: There are many SO posts suggesting that nesting `ObservableObject` can create problems.
In `UserManager`, have you tried using `@Published var model: CentralModel`

Comment: Thanks, but I have. It's just the same problem. CentralModel won't be flagged as changing if an embedded object changes. I'm finding that Swift's reactive model makes a "single source of truth" basically impossible.

Comment: I suggest making `User` and `CentralModel` struct, and removing the
 old Combine `model.user.objectWillChange.sink....` stuff.
 Works well for me in my tests.

Comment: Thanks. But then I have to remember to copy the User back to the central model whenever it's changed. And what if the one in the model is changed while another copy is being manipulated by the UI?

Comment: Without knowing what your code is doing (no minimum code example),
 I can only guess that your statement
 `...I have to remember to copy the User back to the central model whenever it's changed.`,
 is not correct. I'll post my test code to show how changing the user 
 does update the UI.

Comment: Well, if it's a struct it's passed by copy. So if a background process updates the User object in the central data model while the user is editing another copy in a UI, how do you expect to reconcile those two disparate copies afterward?

Comment: The View with `@StateObject ...` takes care of this.

Comment: Not sure what more I can provide without an entire project zipped up and posted somwehere.

Comment: See for reference a good [mcve] from a very related question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68400530/changes-in-nested-observedobject-do-not-updated-the-ui. You don't need hundreds of lines of code in order to produce a [mcve].

Comment: OK, I've added the setup of a timer and how I altered the User object when it fired.

Comment: `sink` is almost always a bad idea

Comment: Why is the Manager an ObservableObject? Every ObservableObject needs to be wrapped at every level in the View with a property wrapper. Using sink with objectWillChange is a gross waste of resources, you would re reloading your entire app with every change instead of targeted redrawing. You need to rethink your approach this setup is not scalable.

Comment: Because the view is deriving its display from the Manager. The sink was just an experiment here to see if the approach would work. The main problem in this entire paradigm is that you have a model, you have views, and you have middlemen between those two that act as brokers between the views and the model. Nowhere have I seen how, exactly, you're supposed to maintain "one source of truth" through that structure. Have you?

Comment: Instead of using sink have the manager use CurrentValueSubject and “assign” the values to a Published. If you have ObservableObject they should be using the provided property wrappers. I use DI for single source of truth + mocking, testing, etc.

Comment: Plus you also have storage. You can easily create storage that is the single source of truth.

Comment: Thanks. In fact I got rid most of this stuff and went back to DI; then I have the UI observing the injected object. Not sure what you mean by "provided property wrappers," though. Or "storage," but either way it seems to me I'll have to implement setter methods on every member of every data structure to send alerts on changes.

Comment: If by wrappers you simply mean Published, I do. The Manager has a published "user status" member that I tweak to elicit changes in the UI. But I can't do that if the manager isn't apprised of changes to the User it's pointing at. Hence my attempt to connect it to said User.

Comment: No ObservedObject, etc. StateObject is for initializing in a View, ObservedObject is for observing objects that live somewhere else. ObservedObject is what you need to see changed for the extra ones. Published isn’t capable of firing for changes in the properties of reference types.

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and put it into a playground.  Once I had fixed all the errors the compiler generated it works fine - the `sink` on `objectWillChange` is called normally.

One thing I noticed along the way was the you were expecting the `objectWillChange` publisher to publish a value.  `objectWillChange` is basically `AnyPublisher<Void, Never>` meaning it will not publish any value (if you put a `.print()` operator in the pipeline ahead of the `sink` you will see it publishes the unit value or `()`) so `receiveValue` doesn't provide you with the `user` the way your code suggests it should.

The next thing that may trip you up is `objectWillChange` is sent during the property's `willSet` handler, and the value of the property will not be set to its new value until AFTER the `objectWillChange` publisher has done its thing.  So you can't retrieve the new `firstName` from the user because the property hasn't changed yet.  This playground will print the previous value of the `firstName` field, but not the new one.

Finally `@Published`, `@ObservableObject` and related mechanisms are primarily intended for interactions between a model and a `SwiftUI` view that is displaying values from that model.

Based on the challenges of that system, it is my opinion that it was ever intended to be used for generic notification of model changes throughout the system.  There are any of a number of other Publish/Subscribe systems you could use.  In comments you mentioned the `NotificationCenter` and that certainly is one choice. `Combine` is another. The `Delegate` pattern is a third option.  Simple closures (callbacks) is also a choice.  As others noted the new macro-based `@Observable` is a better step toward a generic mechanism, but as mentioned in comments - it's new :-(.

At any rate, here is a playground of your code showing something close to what you are trying to do given the caveat's above:

```
import UIKit
import Combine


class User : ObservableObject
{
    @Published var  firstName: String = ""
}

class CentralModel : ObservableObject
{
    @Published var  user: User

    init() {
        user = User()
    }
}

class UserManager : ObservableObject
{
    var model: CentralModel
    private var pubPipelines: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    var validationTimer: Timer?

    init(withModel: CentralModel)
    {
      self.model = withModel

      model.user.objectWillChange
        .sink { print("The user's old first name is \(self.model.user.firstName)") }
        .store(in: &pubPipelines)
    }

    func startValidationCheckTimer()
    {
        self.validationTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.timedValidationCheck), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func timedValidationCheck()
    {
        Task { @MainActor in
          model.user.firstName = UUID().uuidString
          print("Set user's first name to \(model.user.firstName)")
        }
    }
}


let model = CentralModel()
let manager = UserManager(withModel: model)
manager.startValidationCheckTimer()
```

Comment: Thanks very much for that. The receiveValue parameter exists and was auto-completed by the compiler (and built). You can see examples using it: https://www.avanderlee.com/swiftui/published-property-wrapper And this is Combine, is it not? The print statement wasn't really going to be useful; I just plopped it in there to see if the thing was being called.

Comment: Not a print statement the ".print(to:)" publisher operator (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/merge/print(_:to:)) so `model.user.objectWillChange.print().sink(....)`.  It will show you subscriptions and values that go through the pipeline.  The closure accepts a parameter and the autocomplete will put something there, but the value you get will be `()` and not the user.